# Play F4V file with JWplayer on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, jwplayer

I am unable to play a f4v file with a JWplayer on a iOS device: iPhone. The setup code of the player:

```
jwplayer(player).setup({
    file: file,
    primary: "flash",
    autostart: false,
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    autostart: false,
    androidhls: true,
    width: '100%'
});
```

The error i get on the device: "jwplayer error loading media file could not be played".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This needs to be MP4 for iOS support.

Answer (score 1):

An F4V file is a video format that is not supported on iOS (works in Android).

Convert to MP4 for iOS playback.

Comment: Why do you say F4V is a Flash file? Look at the bytes of a MP4 and compare to F4V, they are 99% similar and there is no specific tie-in to any software. An F4V is decodable by any system that chooses to decode the format (just iOS is not such a system, since Apple is invested in MPEG... notice the i-Pod MP3 player?, notice MP4 container is modeled on Apple' own MOV format?... etc). I chose to edit instead of downvoting.

Comment: FLV is based on SWF, while F4V is based on MPEG-4. But they're both referred to as "Flash video," and both came from the Adobe Flash people. And neither one is playable on iOS. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video. And BTW, they're both dead.

Comment: And what do you think the "F" stands for?